# Serializing Null Values from a REST API Response

Tags: xml, serialization

I've recently used WCF to consume a REST API. I used an entity class to serialize REST XML Reponse, here's the part I have a problem:

```
<grid-cell-size type="decimal" nil="true"/>
```

and in my C# class:

```
[XmlElement("grid-cell-size")]
public decimal? GridCellSize { get; set; }
```

but the result is **Input string was not in a correct format.** error message.

How can I change my C# code to accept null values from XML?

Comment: I tested [XmlElement("grid-cell-size"), IsNullable = true] too but no change!

Comment: This works too but I don't want to add extra code!

[XmlElement("grid-cell-size")]
protected string GridCellSizeString { get; set; }

private decimal? _gridCellSize;
public decimal? GridCellSize
{
 get
 {
  if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(GridCellSizeString))
  {
                      return Convert.ToDecimal(GridCellSizeString);
                 }
                 else
                 {
                      return null;
                 }
 }

 set { _gridCellSize = Convert.ToDecimal(value); }
}

Comment: Oh! I found a similar question! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/193185/is-it-possible-to-set-a-default-value-when-deserializing-xml-in-c-net-3-5

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the 'xsi' prefix:
instead of

```
<grid-cell-size type="decimal" nil="true"/>
```

use

```
<grid-cell-size xsi:type="decimal" xsi:nil="true"/>
```

of course - don't forget to add the namespace to the main node: 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"

namespace declarations (if not already declared)